# uploading multiple files restriction is not working using dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code given below it is counting the files when i select the files and alert that you cannot select more than etc...

Limit is 4 and when i select 6 it says cannot select more than 4. But when i select 4 it adds and show thumb anad again on selecting one or 4 it adds again the new 4 or whatever files, so user can upload unlimited files.

How can i catch that selected files and restrict them.

```
<div class="m-form__group form-group row">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
    Select Image
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-9 col-sm-12" id="thumb-output">
        <input id="files" class="" type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('input[type=file]').on('dragenter', function() {
    $('div').addClass('dragover');
});

$('input[type=file]').on('dragleave', function() {
    $('div').removeClass('dragover');
});

if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var numFiles = $('input[type=file]')[0].files.length;

    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files, filesLength = files.length;

    if(files.length > 4){
        alert("you can select max 4 files.");
    }else{
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    }
    });
        } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable to track how many files have been added.

```js
var fileAdded = 0;

...

if(fileAdded + files.length > 4){
    alert("you can select max 4 files.");
} else {
    fileAdded = fileAdded + files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    ...

    }
}
```

Also, please remember to decrease `fileAdded` when the user delete a file.

---

Here is an example:

```js
var fileDict = new Object();

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        var numFiles = $('input[type=file]')[0].files.length;

        $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
            var files = e.target.files, filesLength = files.length;

            if(Object.keys(fileDict).length + files.length > 4){
                alert("you can select max 4 files.");
            }else{
                for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                    var f = files[i];
                    fileDict[f.name] = f;
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                        $("<div class=\"pip\">" +
                          "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + f.name + "\"/>" +
                          "<br/><span class=\"remove\" data-name=\""+f.name+"\">Remove</span>" +
                          "</div>").insertAfter("hr");
                    });
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API");
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  delete fileDict[$(this).data("name")];
  $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
});

var upload = function() {
  let formData = new FormData();
  var i = 0;

  Object.keys(fileDict).forEach(item => {
    formData.append("file" + i, fileDict[item]);
    i += 1;
  });

  $.ajax({ 
      type: 'post', 
      url: '/upload.php',
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: formData ,
      success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
              }
      });
}
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="files" class="" type="file" name="file[]" multiple>

<hr>

<input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="upload()">
```

I am not sure which language you are using for backend. I use PHP here:

```
<?php
if (count($_FILES) > 4) {
  echo "you can select max 4 files.";
} else {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file_id => $file) {
    if ($file['error'] > 0) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $file['error'] . '<br>';
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $file['name']);
      echo 'uploads/' . $file['name'] . '<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It didnot helped

Comment: @usman610 I added an example. Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: it is working now. When i select 4 together then when i remove one and add new file it selects the last file only when you upload. And you can add one by one again and again after removal of one file but it will upload only the last single file added not 4.

Comment: @usman610 File input only remembers the latest files the user chose. And for security reason, we cannot change the value of the file input through code. Nonetheless, you can always create a global object to save all the files the user chose before (`files[i]`) and upload the files in the object instead of the file input. Let me know if you want another example~

Comment: please that will be great if you can give another example but with restriction to select only 4 (with remove button)

Comment: @usman610 Sorry for the delay. I added the code to support uploading files. I am not sure which language you are using for the backend to handle the uploaded file, so I use PHP here. I tested it on my server, and it works fine. Let me know if you need anything else.